# Python - Pandas - Merge two DataFrame with difference timestamp frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, timestamp

I have two dataframe:
- the first one has a timestamp column with second or sub-second time steps,
- the second one has a timestamp column with 1 minute time steps.

Now it's obvious that if the data time interval is the same, both dataframes will have different size because of their different data frequencies.

I want to merge them in a single dataframe using e.g. the higher frequency (i.e. the longest) dataframe and put beside it (horizontally) the other one in such a way to get the correct data for the current timestamp. This means that the lowest frequency dataframe data will repeat themselves according to the current minute data value.

I hope The following example make things more clear:

Dataframe 1

```
|--------------------------|------------------|
|        datetime          |     ValueDF1     |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| 2019-12-11 12:00:16.599  |       1          |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| 2019-12-11 12:00:16.17   |       2          |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| 2019-12-11 12:00:17.11   |       3          |
|--------------------------|------------------|
```

Dataframe 2

```
|--------------------------|------------------|
|        datetime          |     ValueDF2     |
|--------------------------|------------------|
| 2019-12-11 12:00         |       4          |
|--------------------------|------------------|
```

Merged

```
|--------------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|        datetime          |     ValueDF1     |    ValueDF2     |
|--------------------------|------------------|-----------------|
| 2019-12-11 12:00:16.599  |       1          |        4        |    
|--------------------------|------------------|-----------------|
| 2019-12-11 12:00:16.17   |       2          |        4        |
|--------------------------|------------------|-----------------|
| 2019-12-11 12:00:17.11   |       3          |        4        |
|--------------------------|------------------|-----------------|
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 'datetime' columns are all pandas datetime format, we can strip the df1['datetime'] off its seconds and use this new field to merge.

```
df1['datetime_min'] = pd.to_datetime([dt.datetime.strftime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") for d in df1["datetime"]])

df1.merge(df2,left_on='datetime_min', right_on='datetime', how='left')
```

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check `pd.merge_asof()`. Hope this helps:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('datetime'), df2.sort_values('datetime'))
```

Output:

```
                 datetime  ValueDF1  ValueDF2
0 2019-12-11 12:00:16.170         2         4
1 2019-12-11 12:00:16.599         1         4
2 2019-12-11 12:00:17.110         3         4
```